# JavaScript Array valores do php

Tags: javascript, array

Em meu banco de dados tenho

```
id , coluna1, coluna2

1  , 38.951399 ,  -76.958463

2 , 38.942855,   -76.959149
```

Estou utilizando php

Preciso transformar essa informação em um array em JavaScript  com a seguinte estrutura

```
 new Array([38.951399, -76.958463], [38.942855, -76.959149]);
```

A comunicação entre JavaScript em Php está ok, no js consigo imprimir no console strings,  o que não consigo e fazer essa  conversão dessas strings para um Array em JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monte a array no php primeiro, depois dê a saída com:

```
echo json_encode($minhaArray);
```

O resultado será:

```
[[38.951399, -76.958463], [38.942855, -76.959149]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `json_encode()`:

```
<?php

$array = array(
    '1' => array('38.951399' ,  '-76.958463'),
    '2' => array('38.951399' ,  '-76.958463'),
);

$var = json_encode($array);
```

Já na `view`, você imprime assim:

```
<script> var javascriptArray = <?php echo $var ?> </script>
```

Comment: neoprofit estou trbalhando bem parecido como vc postou...desculpe mas sou inciante,  estou jquery para chamar o php  portanto eu tenho e consigo percorrer  um array igual ao que vc postou... a questão é  preciso passar esse resultado  como parametro para outra função que está esperando o seguinte valor.
new Array([38.951399, -76.958463], [38.942855, -76.959149]);

No php estou retornando uma matriz de array...

Comment: Não consegui entender o cenário :/   Que tal melhorar a pergunta?

Comment: neoprofit  me confundi seu exemplo  funcionou obrigado!